# rms package Glm: how to add indicators in the formula

Tags: r, rms

I am trying to build a glm model using Glm() from rms package in R.
But I don't know the correct expression in Glm formula for the indicators.

Allow me use iris data as an example,
In the base R `glm` function, my code works and it is like below:

```
model1 = glm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + ifelse(Sepal.Width==3,1,0),data=iris)
```

But if I use the same formula in `Glm`, it will return

```
 model2 = Glm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + ifelse(Sepal.Width==3,1,0),data=iris)
```

> Error in if (!length(fname) || !any(fname == zname)) { : 
>       missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Or if I use

```
model3 = Glm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + asis(Sepal.Width==3),data=iris)
```

> Error in if (asc[i] == 8) next : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I just don't know the correct way to define this transformation. Also I know I can solve this by putting this indicator as a new column in the data, but then I could not use `rms`'s `Predict()` function to generate the correct plot.

Comment: Looks like `Glm()` handles formulas differently than `glm()`. It doesn't seem to like that you have two different covariates based off the same column in the data.frame.  You can try contacting the package authors but this doesn't look like a quick fix. If you did the transformation of the data.frame to include the indicator, you could use the same transformation during `predict()`. Just wrap it in a function and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you Flick,  I agree that creating new columns is a good alternative solution. I will try to make it work for Predict( ) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, this seems to work fine (I don't really know what I'm doing with `datadist`, but fumbling through ...)

```
 iris$sepal3 <- as.numeric(iris$Sepal.Width==3)
 library(rms)
 ddist <- with(iris,datadist(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, sepal3))
 options(datadist="ddist")
 model1 <- Glm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + sepal3,
               data=iris)
 plot(Predict(model1))
```

(I do get a warning message about `Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated`, but I think that's because I'm using a development version of R with rms version 5.1.0 ...

Comment: My point is that if I use `plot(Predict(model1, Sepal.Width))`, then it won't reflect the indicator at 3 as I guess the model treats Sepal.Width and sepal3 as independent variables. Therefore I prefer to put the indicator into the formula instead of data